# cannot look up values in pandas df with the reference number with leading 0

Tags: pandas, dataframe, zero

I'm trying to get the description from a dataframe by entering the item number.  However, python3 does not support numbers starting with 0.

From the below code, I'm looking up in a df with the style no equal to '0400271' and return the description of that row.  The code works only for numbers not starting with 0. For leading 0 numbers, it just returns an empty series.

```
joe.loc[joe['STYLE_NO'] == '0400271', 'DESCRIPTION']

#also separately tried: (also returns empty series) 
value = '0400271'.zfill(7)
print(value)
print(type(value))
b = joe.query('STYLE_NO == @value')['DESCRIPTION']
b
```

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 are not permitted in Python. The obvious workaround would be to extract `'0400271'.lstrip('0')` or perhaps explicitly convert it to a number with `int('0400271')`

Comment: i cannot just strip it as i need the 0 in front for something later. i know python doesn't allow it but there has to be a way around it.

Comment: Make a copy and strip from that then.

Comment: no i need to keep the 0 as its a unique identifier. it won't work because its a unique key that i need for later steps not mentioned here

Comment: In your case, I would prefer to convert your dataframe to dict with "orient" attribute to "list" like this: `_test = joe.loc[:, "STYLE_NO"].to_dict(orient="list")`. Now becomes easy, all you have to do is check: `True if "0400271" in _test['STYLE_NO'] else False` in a loop or whatever you think it s the most reasonably solution for your purposes. Or you can you create a second DATAFRAME with APPLYMAP associedated extracting only those matched values.